# How to write a plugin loader for a module written in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on a module that as part of its startup will load in dynamically other modules based on a configuration file, which provided the name of packages or files to import. I had something written up in vanilla JS that worked well, but I'm struggling to translating it to Typescript.

In Javascript, I was doing:

./src/main.js (assume `config.plugins = ['./plugin']`):

```
class ModuleName {
  constructor(config) {
    for (let plugin of config.plugins) {
      let register = require(plugin);
      register(this);
    }
  }
}
```

./src/plugin.js:

```
class Plugin() {
}

module.exports = (main_module) => {
  main_module.plugin = new Plugin();
}
```

Attempting to translate this to Typescript got me to (with the main perceived difference being that the plugins are loaded now asynchronously, which is a problem, but that at least compiles, so not my focus here):

./src/main.ts:

```
interface Config {
  plugins: string[];
}

interface Plugin {
  register(main_module: ModuleName): void;
}

export class ModuleName {
  public config: Config;
  public constructor(config: Config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  public async init(): Promise<string[]> {
    return this.loadPlugins(this.config.plugins);
  }

  // You don't need to return anything from here because `async` functions
  // always return a `Promise`.
  private async loadPlugins(plugins: string[]): Promise<string[]> {
    for (let plugin of plugins) {
      // Here using `async`/`await` is a lot less complicated than using
      // `then()` because of the `for...of` loop
      let loaded: Plugin = await import(plugin);
      loaded.register(this);
    }
    return plugins;
  }
}
```

./src/plugin.ts:

```
import { ModuleName } from './index';

declare module './index' {
  export interface ModuleName {
    plugin: Plugin;
  }
}

export class Plugin {
  public foo(): void {
    console.log('Plugin::foo');
  }
}

export function register(main_module: ModuleName): void {
  main_module.plugin = new Plugin();
}
```

now, in the main.ts it allows me to reference `this.plugin` freely. However, when I attempt to import this into a project, I don't can't reference the plugin.

For example, compiling the above to the `./dist` folder, and having the following (at the root of my project):

./test.ts

```
import { ModuleName } from './dist';

let a = new ModuleName({plugins: ['./plugin']});
a.init().then(a.plugin.foo()).catch(console.error);
```

errors with tsc saying `Property 'plugin' does not exist on type 'ModuleName'.`

Comment: You would need to `export` the plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're loading it asynchronously and probably attempting to access it too quickly. It's definitely not a good idea to use `setTimeout` to ensure asynchronous processes are completed when you need them (what if the process takes 50 ms on a fast computer, but 500 on a slow one?); instead, you want to access the `Promise` directly so you can use `Promise.then()`. The problem is you never want to return anything but the object itself from a constructor, so you never want to have asynchronous constructors. A better pattern would be to have a separate initialization function that performs the asynchronous process.

Furthermore, `import(plugin)` returns a `Promise`, not the plugin itself. Therefore, you must also handle this accordingly and wait to resolve the `Promise` returned by `loadPlugins` until after all of the `import`s resolve. That's probably not a very easy statement to read, so here's some code which can explain it far better than I can:

```
export class ModuleName {
  private config: Config;

  public constructor(config: Config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  public async init(): Promise<void> {
    return this.loadPlugins(this.config.plugins);
  }

  // You don't need to return anything from here because `async` functions
  // always return a `Promise`.
  private async loadPlugins(plugins: string[]): Promise<void> {
    for (let plugin of plugins) {
      // Here using `async`/`await` is a lot less complicated than using
      // `then()` because of the `for...of` loop
      let loaded: Plugin = await import(plugin);
      loaded.register(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when initializing, you need to properly handle the asynchronous initialization:

```js
let a = new ModuleName(config);
a.init().then(() => {
  a.plugin.foo();
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

or even just this will work:

```js
let a = new ModuleName(config);
a.init().then(a.plugin.foo).catch(console.error)
```

Comment: While this is a better way to handle the loading of plugins asynchronously, this does not solve the bigger problem that I still cannot reference any of the plugins when importing the module as TS throws an error.

Comment: If you update the `main.ts` as I have here, it should work (it works for me at least). Are you passing the config object to `new ModuleName();`? In `plugin.ts` you have `main_module: Module` but it should be `main_module: ModuleName`.

Comment: That was a typo. I've updated my question using your suggestions for async, and to show what my main.ts looks like/located and how it's referring to the module. Like I said, if I put the above class instantation inside of ./src/index.ts it works, but inside ./test.ts (which references the compiled version of the module), no dice.

Comment: Additionally, this is just assuming that the plugins are being loaded from the same folder as the index.ts. What happens when the plugins are loaded from say `@name/module-plugin1`?

Comment: @MasterOdin it looks like due to the way you're importing the module (from a string after compilation) you need to reference the JavaScript file, not the TypeScript file. I was able to get it to work using `let config =  { plugins: ["./plugin.js"] };` You'll need to use the path relative to your output (transpiled) files.

Comment: I made a repo to illustrate my setup here https://github.com/MasterOdin/typescript-module-test and what I'm doing and seeing since I feel like I've messed something up here as I'm not sure how you're not getting a compilation error (though it does run just fine).

Comment: Your `tsconfig` only includes ts files in the `src` directory. Either move `test.ts` to `src` and import from `./index` or add `"test.ts"` to `"include"` in `tsconfig.json` and import from `./src`. The TypeScript checker is not properly checking your file.

Comment: Also note: the TypeScript compiler automatically fixes your imports, so import TypeScript files, not JavaScript files. On the other hand, when you are writing your own asynchronous import function, the compiler is not smart enough to update the references in your `config` object. So you do `import { ModuleName } from './src';` but in the same file `{ plugins: ['./plugin.js'] }`.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. Thank you for your help.